# i want to display JSON result in reactJs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

[This is my JSON result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtZA8.png)

Using Map function to display JSON array elements in reactJs.I have tried with the following code. I'm unable to get results and it says "Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null".  Kindly help me to solve this.

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './js/components/Header';
import './App.css';
import './dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import cookie from 'react-cookie';
import Request from 'superagent';
import { browserHistory  } from 'react-router';

export default class Performance extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        fullName : cookie.load('fullName'),
        empId : cookie.load('empId'),
        userResults : false
    };       
    if(cookie.load('empId') === undefined ){
        browserHistory.push('/login')
    }   
    
}
 getInitialState(){
    return {userResults:false};
 }

 componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    var url = 'http://192.168.1.93:8081/employee/dashboard';
    Request
        .get(url)
        .query({ empId: this.state.empId })
         .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8')
        .set('Authorization', 'Basic aHJtczox')
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .end(function(err, res){
            self.setState({userResults:  res.body});
           console.log(self.state.userResults); 
        });
  }
 
  render() {        
        return ( 
        <div>
        <Header />  
            <div className="container ">
                <form className="form-signin1"> 
                <h2 className="form-signin-heading">Customer Orientation{this.props.userButtons}</h2>
                <table className="table text-center" >
                    <thead>
                        <th >Deliverables</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            this.state.userResults.response.QuestionSection.map(function(res){
                                res.question.map(function(res1){
                                    return (
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{res1.question}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    )
                                })
                            })
                        }
                        <tr><td>sdfsdf</td></tr>              
                    </tbody>
                </table>                
                <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button">Sign in</button>
                </form>
            </div> 
        </div>
            
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `this.state.userResults.response` doesn't exist initially you get this error. Its is better of performing a check before iterating. Also you need to return the result of inner `map` function too like

```
  {
         this.state.userResults.response && this.state.userResults.response.QuestionSection.map(function(res){
              return res.question.map(function(res1){
                    return (
                        <tr>
                            <td>{res1.question}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )
               })
          })
 }
```

Comment: Its skipping the loop while checking

Comment: It wont once the data is available. you can console.log(this.state.userResults.response) to see if data is available

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes you are correct data is not available at that time. In which way to get the results.

Comment: Check if your request is to fetch data is getting success or error in the componentDidMount and once you get the data, your component will work

Comment: componentDidMount is fetching the result but unable to render the result.

Comment: try `.end(function(err, res){
            self.setState({userResults:  res.body}, function() {  console.log(self.state.userResults)});
          
        });` and see what result you get and check if `this.state.userResults.response.QuestionSection` is an array

Comment: yes i'm getting below result

{
 "response_code": "0",
 "response_message": "Success",
 "response_method": "DASHBOARD",
 "response": {
  "apprisalId": 1,
  "apprisalTitle": "Performance Review Nov-2016",
  "QuestionSection": [{
   "sectionTitle": "Customer Orientation",
   "isMandatory": 0,
   "question": [{
    "qusId": 1,
    "question": "Number of customer appreciations / acknowledgement for the solution provided >=",
    "weightage": 15,
    "ansId": null
   }]
  }]
 }
}

Comment: Can you share the result of this.state.userResults.response.QuestionSelection

Comment: [{
 "sectionTitle": "Customer Orientation",
 "isMandatory": 0,
 "question": [{
  "qusId": 1,
  "question": "Number of customer appreciations / acknowledgement for the solution provided >=",
  "weightage": 15,
  "ansId": null,
  "isChecked": null,
  "employeeWeightage": null,
  "justification": null
 }]
}]

Comment: was banging my head against the wall until I realised that you have missed the return statement in the inner map function and I failed to spot it for a long time. It sure will work now. I have updated the answer

Comment: Ya its working now. Thank you so much for your timely help.

Comment: Wonderful answer @Shubham Khatri

Comment: In order to mark the answer as accepted you need to click the tick that is present under the score on left hand side

Comment: I unable to give.